# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Im trying to use fortnite api to display current item shop and i'm getting error likein the title, when I console log result it show an array but i cant map through it ? whY?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
export default function itemShop() {
    const [shop, setShop] = useState('')
    const API = 'https://fortnite-public-api.theapinetwork.com/prod09/store/get?language={en}'
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                API,
            );

            setShop(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const { items } = shop;
    console.log(items)
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{shop.date}</p>
            {items.map(item => <p>{item.name}</p>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

code sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/embed/km10wq4y5

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to check items isn't null/undefined before rendering:

```
{items && items.map(item => (
        <p>{item.name}</p>
      ))}
```

Working: https://codesandbox.io/s/24vkqzn6xy

Answer (score 5):

Problem is in this line:

```
const [shop, setShop] = useState('')
```

Since you are expecting `shop.items` as an array, so define the initial state as:

```
const [shop, setShop] = useState({ items: [] });
```

Also assign unique key to each `p`, here:

```
<p key={item.itemid}>{item.name}</p>
```

[Working Code.](https://codesandbox.io/s/8449100yl)

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it like this

```
{ items?.map(item => (<p>{ item.name }</p>)) }
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I forget to add **await** in **axios** after calling **async** method. like the code below. Make sure to check your code again if above methods didn't help you.

```
async function getCategories() {
      try {
        const response = axios.get("API");
        setCategories(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone wants to understand this problem and its solution can visit the site web it was really helpful for me
https://www.debuggr.io/react-map-of-undefined/